# Eclipse: how to format all xml files in workspace?

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatting

I greatly appreciate the functionality of Eclipse to apply code formatter to all projects in workspace, however it works only for *Java* files, I'd like now to apply formatter to all *XML* files. And there are a pack of them: `pom's`, *Spring* configs etc.

I've found no build-in format that could do the task for all selected projects. So, my question, do you know an external plugin that would do the task (possibly with own format settings that could be exported/imported)? Or I have missed an existing option?

Comment: It should just be in the Source menu of the file/folder/whatever.

Comment: Source->format works when on single xml file, when on project/group of projects, it formats only java code

Comment: did you got answer to your question?

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I did:  File Search for all files with file name pattern *.xml.  In Search results, select all and then right click, Source -> Format.  I'm on Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, not sure how far back this feature goes.

Comment: Right-click a folder with xml files and select Source -> Format works also.

Comment: @bjmi That's not what OP asked. His xml files are spread across multiple projects (and probably across multiple folders within each project), and he wants a single manipulation to format all of them. What you suggests requires to be done on each of the (potentially numerous) folders...